# How to remove the last character of a UTF-8 string in C++?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, unicode, utf-8

The text is stored in a `std::string`.

If the text is 8-bit ASCII, then it is really easy:

```
text.pop_back();
```

But what if it is UTF-8 text?
As far as I know, there are no UTF-8 related functions in the standard library which I could use.

Comment: What do you mean by *"character"*? Code unit? Code point? Grapheme cluster?

Comment: The last unicode character of the string, which is represented using UTF8

Comment: use `std::basic_string` instead of `std::string`. `pop_back` is a method for both

Comment: @polfosol: How should `std::basic_string` help? You need a UTF library to manipulate a UTF text encoding.

Comment: It has to be a simple `std::string`, which contains UTF8 text

Comment: `basic_string<wchar_t>` maybe? @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Comment: either find a nice utf8 library or learn the utf8 structure and implement it yourself

Comment: @IInspectable a character is a code point, duh.

Comment: IterAtor I think you've missed @IInspectable's point. In unicode, "character" is an ambiguous notion, regardless of encoding method (UTF8, UTF16, etc). That's why they asked for clarification on what you mean by "character". A forewarning; the standard library basically has no support for unicode. You're going to have to turn to a unicode-specific library.

Comment: @self: I believe you grossly underestimate the complexity that is Unicode. What about U+0301 (*combining acute accent*)? Or U+200C (*zero width non joiner*)? How about U+FB00 (*latin small ligature ff*)? Each one is assigned a code point, and neither one is perceived as a character.

Comment: @IInspectable Interesting concept: Should ff become f? ß become s? And, even, å become a (but only for Norwegian text)?

Comment: @polfosol: Doubling the size of the underlying representation does not give you a UTF-aware string. See the comments (and the downvotes!) on Stephane's answer, which proposes what you proposed.

Comment: @TomBlodget: That very much depends on the application. The requirements are different, if you implement a transfer protocol, where code points must not straddle package boundaries, or if you implement a text editor's backspace handler. Since neither requirement is better, or more right than the others, I asked for clarification.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You really need a [UTF-8 Library](https://sourceforge.net/projects/utfcpp/) if you are going to work with `UTF-8`. However for this task I think something like this may suffice:

```
void pop_back_utf8(std::string& utf8)
{
    if(utf8.empty())
        return;

    auto cp = utf8.data() + utf8.size();
    while(--cp >= utf8.data() && ((*cp & 0b10000000) && !(*cp & 0b01000000))) {}
    if(cp >= utf8.data())
        utf8.resize(cp - utf8.data());
}

int main()
{
    std::string s = "κόσμε";

    while(!s.empty())
    {
        std::cout << s << '\n';
        pop_back_utf8(s);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
κόσμε
κόσμ
κόσ
κό
κ
```

It relies on the fact that [UTF-8 Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) has one *start byte* followed by several *continuation bytes*. Those *continuation bytes* can be detected using the provided bitwise operators.

Comment: This is still an issue if you are using combining glyphs:

`κόσÄÄμε
κόσÄÄμ
κόσÄÄ
κόσÄA
κόσÄ
κόσ
κό
κ`

Comment: @Taywee What do you mean "combining glyphs"? It seems to work fine with that string.

Comment: he means "combining character". This code will potentially remove just the last combining character (think an umlaut), but not up to the base character. The result will be a string that potentially loses its meaning, rather than chopping the last grapheme cluster (aka. what a reader would consider to be a "character") off of the string.

Comment: @CoryNelson I've just been reading about them. Well I think they seem to operate at a different level. Popping code-points is fundamentally `UTF-8` whereas combining characters seem to be *convention* that applications may or may not use. I think its probably for the application level to decide how many code points to pop to remove a given glyph.

Comment: Yes, I meant combining character.  Sorry I wasn't clear.  Look at my example.  The first `Ä` is a single codepoint, whereas the second one is an `A` mixed with a combining umlaut.  The second one has the umlaut removed before the `A`, which may or may not be what OP is asking for.  Sorry, I'm not fully familiar with the conventional terms.

Comment: @Taywee I am with you now. For some reason my code appears to work fine with the example string you gave. Maybe in transit something has normalized those code-points to contain only self-contained ones? I think combining code points like this is fundamentally a different level. UTF8 may set aside code-point values for applications to use to build combined glyphs but it doesn't define them for every language in existence.  I think it  is for applications to apply such conventions as are appropriate to whatever language they are dealing with rather than text processing primitives like this.

Comment: It's pretty likely that stackoverflow normalizes the input of comments and the like.  This solution is good, I'm just pointing out that depending on the input, it might have unexpected effects (especially in some cases like zero-width unicode characters).  I'm pretty sure you'd have the same issue with a real unicode library, as it would still contain each codepoint as its own character.

Comment: @CoryNelson FWIW, removing the last grapheme cluster might also result in a string that loses its meaning. It all depends on what meaning is in question here.

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is pop off characters until you reach the leading byte of a code point. The leading byte of a code point in UTF8 is either of the pattern `0xxxxxxx` or `11xxxxxx`, and all non-leading bytes are of the form `10xxxxxx`. This means you can check the first and second bit to determine if you have a leading byte.

```
bool is_leading_utf8_byte(char c) {
    auto first_bit_set = (c & 0x80) != 0;
    auto second_bit_set = (c & 0X40) != 0;
    return !first_bit_set || second_bit_set;
}

void pop_utf8(std::string& x) {
    while (!is_leading_utf8_byte(x.back()))
        x.pop_back();
    x.pop_back();
}
```

This of course does no error checking and assumes that your string is valid utf-8.

Comment: Why are `first_bit_set` and `second_bit_set` auto, and not bool?

Comment: This works for the simplest of cases.  Note that this will fail if you are using combining characters, as it will simply remove the combining character from its glyph, rather than remove the glyph entirely.

Comment: @IterAtor: Because I always use auto. You don't have to.

Comment: You could simplify `is_leading_utf8_byte` to `return (c & 0xC0) != 0x80` to test that it is not a trailing byte (`10xxxxxx`).